# Queries in magento installation about encryption and stuffs

Tags: magento

While magento installation on bottom there are two things comes in mind and each installation i am ignoring that.one is what exactly is the web access options and another one is what is the usage of encryption key

These may sounds not important but i am just trying to know that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The encryption key is used to SALT customer passwords, and to encrypt any card details when required.  You can find it in `local.xml` after installation.